# Google-search lens for unity

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, search, google

Is there a plugin (lens) for Unity Dash that allows me to do google searches and open the links in my browser? If so, what is it called and how do I install it??

Comment: This may be of interest to you. https://launchpad.net/unity-gdata-lens